# Ajuda com Modulos - Javascript Nativo (ES6)

Tags: javascript

Preciso de uma ajuda simples com módulos javascript, estou estudando e tenho muitas dúvidas.

No meu exemplo, carrego o `Fetch.js,` que é um arquivo exclusivo que eu uso para fazer solicitações, `GET, PUT, POST e DELETE`, e tudo está indo bem até agora.

Portanto, tenho um arquivo `AppController.js`, onde obtenho alguns dados do aplicativo, como o nome do aplicativo, por exemplo.

**AppController.js**

```
import Fetch from './Fetch.js';

// GET
async function getApplication() {
    return await Fetch.get('/application');
}

export default getApplication;
```

Então, eu tenho outro arquivo `Index.js`, onde importo `AppController.js`

**Index.js**

```
import InfoApplication from './AppController.js';

let ObjectApplication = {};

const initApplication = () => {
    InfoApplication();
}

initApplication();
```

**Fetch.js**

```
// Fetch.js
const _apiHost = 'http://banco_de_dados';

async function request(url, params, method = 'GET') {

  const options = {
    method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  if (params) {   
    if (method === 'GET') {
      url += '?' + objectToQueryString(params);
    } else {        
      options.body = JSON.stringify(params);      
    }
  }

  const response = await fetch(_apiHost + url, options);

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    return generateErrorResponse('The server responded with an unexpected status.');
  }

  const result = await response.json();

  return result;

}

function objectToQueryString(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(key => key + '=' + obj[key]).join('&'); 
}

function generateErrorResponse(message) {
  return {
    status : 'error',
    message
  };
}

function get(url, params) {   
  return request(url, params);
}

function create(url, params) {    
  return request(url, params, 'POST');
}

 function update(url, params) {
  return request(url, params, 'PUT');
}

function remove(url, params) {   
  return request(url, params, 'DELETE');
}

export default {
  get,
  create,
  update,
  remove
};
```

**E aqui começa minha dúvida:**

***Pergunta:***

Quero armazenar o retorno da solicitação em um objeto global, para que eu possa acessar as propriedades desse objeto em qualquer lugar, é possível?

Por exemplo:

`ObjectApplication.name`

Comment: se está usando somente nodejs ou algum framework js?

Comment: Não achei o IIFE citado pergunta. Não estaria tentando fazer algo assim `(function () {InfoApplication()})()`, mesmo que signifique o mesmo de somente  `InfoApplication()`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, não estou utilizando nodejs e não estou utilizando nenhum `webpack` ou framework. É JS nativo!

Comment: ta errado isso aqui: `getApplication()` por causa da parte interna e falta tanta coisa que a sua pergunta é ruim, não tem fundamento, não tem como responder e não disse para que veio ...

Comment: @AugustoVasques, isso me ajuda quanto a pergunta 1, mas tenho a segunda pergunta que para mim é mais complexa de entender, pensei em `singletons`, mas não imagino como utilizar neste modulo.

Comment: não faça duas perguntas em uma. É desagradável para responder e é contrário as normas do site.

Comment: Onde está fazendo isso ... já que não usa nodejs?

Comment: Estou fazendo em js puro, somente criei os arquivos em .js e carregando um arquivo HTML desta forma:

`<script type="module" src"./index.js"></scritp>`

Comment: e não está dando algum erro na tela, porque deveria?

Comment: não está com nenhum erro! somente quero saber se é possivel armazenar o retorno da requisição em um objeto e acessar este objeto em qualquer lugar da aplicação

Comment: Sim é possível.

Comment: pode ser que não tenha erro, mas, por exemplo o seu `getApplication()` não faz nada ele simplesmente tem um `const` com chamada em um `Fetch` que não sabemos a implementação e se for requisição pode ser feito com `fetch` ... sei lá acho que seu código tem diversos problemas.

Comment: é possivel mas, não com esse código...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, o `getApplication()` faz uma requisição, veja que no inicio do arquivo, faço tambem a importação de outro arquivo Fetch.js, e neste Fetch, tenho o método get

Comment: Esse `getApplication()` lhe dá uma const com um promisse, mas, isso não está resolvido, ou seja, não sabemos como foi implementado e não temos como adivinhar. ou coloca todo o codigo ou refaça a pergunta e parece que a sua duvida é até outra.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, coloquei todo o código

Comment: o seu `getApplication()` precisa somente de um `return` então `async function getApplication() {
   return await Fetch.get('/application');
}`

Comment: E qual a dificuldade que você encontrou para armazenar o retorno da solicitação em uma variável global?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, ótimo, tambem funcionou com `return`, mas eu quero que este retorno fique neste objeto `ObjectApplication`

Comment: @v.Santos minha dificuldade eh como armazenar o retorno da requisição no objectApplication

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> let ObjectApplication = {};
> ```

Escolha uma opção

```
window.ObjectApplication = null;
```

```
globalThis.ObjectApplication = null;
```

```
this.ObjectApplication = null;
```

```
(0, eval)('this').ObjectApplication = null;
```

Então

```
InfoApplication().then(app => ObjectApplication = app);
```

Comment: Não está certo, eu quero atribuir o retorno da requisição a este objeto, e não definir um objeto vazio.

Comment: @WagnerFillio, `window.ObjectApplication = InfoApplication()`?